# Batch import json files to MongoDB using scripting

Tags: json, mongodb, batch-file, sh

I have been trying to import a a set of json file into MongoDB using a script as shown below

```
for i in /home/betafish/Desktop/clsnr/*.json; 
do
  mongoimport --dbpath /home/betafish/Desktop/mongodb/data/db  clsnr --collection ${i/.json/} --file $i
done
```

The JSON files are in `/home/betafish/Desktop/clsnr/` folder and the MongoDB database path is as shown in the script.

when trying to run the script it throws the following error

```
mDBimport.sh: 2: mDBimport.sh: Bad substitution
```

I think, this has something to do with db path or actually accessing the mongoimport command. Any pointers as to what might be causing this problem would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in /home/betafish/Desktop/clsnr/*.json; 
do
  mongoimport --db <db-name> --collection <collection-name> ${i}
done
```

See, if that helps.